# how to delete rows when you have text in a cell

Tags: excel

Thank for the other responses that i have had,

I have a another question.

I am trying to delete rows that contain text and just keep the cells that have numbers in.

I have two columns A and B i am trying to reference the cells in "B1:B100"
some cells have a number in it which i want to keep and the rest have text that will change i have tried use a test to find any "A",","b","C" is there any way of just saying any text and blanks in the cell range then delete rows

So i am just left with two two columns with name in A and number in column B

I have been able to specify letters but can only specify one varable not mulitple ones

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
on error resume next
range("b1:b100").specialcells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).entirerow.delete
range("b1:b100").specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks).entirerow.delete
on error goto 0
```